# Why is the left margin of the navigation links larger than the right?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make my first website draft but I noticed the left margin problem. I tried removing all nav properties and classes from the stylesheet but the left margin is still larger. Any help is appreciated, thank you. I'm still new with this forum so please correct me if I did anything wrong with my format. (View the snippet/code in full page to see the left margin problem)

```css
html {
  background: url("Images/char2.jpg") fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.bg-opacity {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

h1 {
  font-family: courier;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  animation: party-header 0.5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes party-header {
  0% {text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px gray, 0px -3px 3px gray, 3px 0px 3px gray, -3px 0px 3px gray;}
  100% {text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px gold, 0px -3px 3px gold, 3px 0px 3px gold, -3px 0px 3px gold;}
}

.navflexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navflexcontainer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px;
  font-family: "times";
  font-size: 23px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 8px white, 0px -2px 8px white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body class="bg-opacity">
<h1><a href="#">VIP Black Market<a></h1>
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navflexcontainer">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cryptocurrency</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Loan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your `a` tag in your `h1`. It's causing the browser to create empty fragments breaking the UI

Comment: cant believe i made a simple mistake. thanks! :D